# Do Anonymous\concrete subclasses inherit abstract parent private fields?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I understand that an abstract class can't be instantiated. Yet, if we write something like code represented below, it will instantiate an anonymous subclass of the abstract parent one. According to Java specifications the subclass object should not have access to its parent private members.

What is puzzling me that the anonymous subclass object is able to access a **private** field of the abstract parent class by printing the value stored in "i". What misunderstanding do I have?

```
public class Main {

public static void main (String [] args){


    B myB = new B() {};
    myB.print();


}}


public abstract class B {

private int i = 5;

public void print(){
    System.out.println(i);
}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is perfectly fine, as `i` is being accessed by a method in `B`. The fact that `print()` is being called by code in another class does not matter; visibility modifiers only affect *direct* accesses.

(You don't need anonymous subclasses to show this; you would have seen the same effect with a concrete class.)

This is how encapsulation is supposed to work: it would have been very hard for different classes to use each other in productive ways if they couldn't invoke methods in other classes that use private fields. It's `B`'s responsibility to implement its `public` methods in such a way that its private fields aren't adversely affected by those methods being called.